# Color histogram similarity vs Template matching for "Video Matching"

Tags: histogram, template-matching

I'm planning to create an application to check the similarity of two given videos by comparing the similarity of frames in the video. i think this can be done using both "color histogram" similarity and "Template matching". could someone please suggest me what is the best technique for this? and the advantage of using it?